# wcf bindings - service and client dont match

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a wcf service that has been used by a client for the past while.

Both client and service use basicHttpBinding where no additional settings are present.

I now have a new client calling into the service for a large amount of data which results in an exception on the client side as it goes over the default 65536 size.

So I added maxReceivedMessageSize as suggested on many answers to this issue

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding 
            name="Service1BasicHttpBinding" 
            maxReceivedMessageSize="6024800" 
            maxBufferPoolSize="6024800">
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

This was added to both service and client,
Service:

```
<services>
    <service name="MyService" >
        <endpoint
            binding="basicHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="Service1BasicHttpBinding"
            contract="MyServiceContract" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Client:

```
<client>
    <endpoint
        address="http:myendpoint"
        binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="Service1BasicHttpBinding"
        contract="MyServiceContract"
            name="MyService" />
</client>
```

And all works well.
My question is I have **not** updated my other client to have the same binding and bindingConfiguration(Service1BasicHttpBinding) and it still works.
Why does this work?
I cant find anywhere that says the client and server will work if the bindings are different and am both puzzled and curious to why it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the settings you updated are specific to the client, and have no meaning to the service (and vice versa).

While the binding protocol and the security settings need to match between the service and the client, things like timeouts, max received message size, reader quotas, etc are specific to the application that owns the config file where they are defined.

In other words, the client may say "I can except a message that is 6024800 big", and the service doesn't care.  Now, if the client tries to *send* a message to the service that is bigger than what the service will accept, you'll get an error.